# NHibernate SaveOrUpdate() improperly working with GeneratedBy.Assigned()

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, identifier

NHibernate's documentations specifically says

> 5.1.4.7. Assigned Identifiers
>
> If you want the application to assign identifiers (as opposed to having NHibernate generate them), you may use the assigned generator. This special generator will use the identifier value already assigned to the object's identifier property. Be very careful when using this feature to assign keys with business meaning (almost always a terrible design decision).
>
> Due to its inherent nature, entities that use this generator cannot be saved via the ISession's SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you have to explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or updated by calling either the Save() or Update() method of the ISession.

But I am using assigned identifiers and session.SaveOrUpdate() and I'm not getting an error/warning of any sort.

What am I missing? Did they change how SaveOrUpdate behaves and now it can be used with assigned identifiers?

I am also using Fluent NHibernate's auto mapping.

Here's the code:

```
 public class MyIDConvention : IIdConvention
 {
      public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
        {
            instance.GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        }
 }
 
 private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
 {
      return Fluently.Configure().Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("testDB.db"))
      .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>(cfg).Conventions.Add<MyIDConvention>()
      .BuildSessionFactory();
 }
```

I'm expecting an error when I do:

```
 Product myProduct = new Product(presetID);
 session.SaveOrUpdate(myProduct);
 transaction.Commit();
```

but nothing happens.

If I had left out the myIDConvention, then I get the error:
NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect).

Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score -1):

When using assigned ids NHibernate can determine if the entity is persistent by comparing the id to the unsaved value setting. My understanding is that the unsaved value setting allows SaveOrUpdate to be used and the documentation you referenced is outdated/misleading.

For example, if your id is int the default unsaved-value is 0.

[5.1.4](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id)

> unsaved-value (optional - defaults to a "sensible" value): An
>   identifier property value that indicates that an instance is newly
>   instantiated (unsaved), distinguishing it from transient instances
>   that were saved or loaded in a previous session.

Comment: Say my id is type int and the unsaved-value is 0 and say my presetID is 5, that would imply to NHibernate that myProduct (with id 5) is an update. However, I'm not updating, I am saving since I just created the object and am inserting it into the DB. How is it knowing this? Also, as a side note the section I referenced 5.1.4.7 is 7 sub-sub-sub section away from 5.1.4 of the same file...

Comment: You're right and I'm wrong (mostly). After re-reading my take on this is that SaveOrUpdate is simply ignored for assigned ids and doesn't throw an exception. However, I think that the unsaved-value setting causes persistent objects to be updated without an explicit call to Update (but I didn't test this).